# Vite sourcemaps show in inspector, but loads different sourcemap in browser

Tags: vite, source-maps, vite-plugin-development

Vite doesn't serve my transform sourcemaps even though they are available in the pipeline,

I'm building a framework plugin and not able to get vite to correctly serve sourcemaps.

Using `vite-plugin-inspect` here is the pipeline:

[image: vite pipeline]

The sourcemaps are working during the plugin transform step:

[image].

The only other step after this one is the vite-import-analysis that does not have a "sourcemap" button in the inspector. However, the browser has a file with a different source that appears to identical to the file itself. Here is the sourcemap embedded via `sourceMappingURL=data:application/json` loaded into sourcemap visualizer:

[image]

I set up a repo on StackBlitz and *included the actual plugin code* as I suspect it may be how I am using vite:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-kxfbbf?file=plugin.js

For comparison, here is a [SolidJS Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/solidjs-templates-gw5aof) that correctly serves the source file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that directly passing the mozilla SourcMapGeneator instance as the return `map` "SourceMap" value. Perhaps because of my poor variable choice (`sourceMap`) my brain connected the two ‍♂️. But the generator is *not* the sourcemap (it *produces* the sourcemap). The solution is to use the `.toJSON()` method which returns a sourcemap v3 object:

```js
return {
    code,
    map: smGenerator.toJSON(),
};
```